# VBA Userforms used with no explicit instantiation

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Let's say I have a userform called `MyUserForm` that I use like

```
Dim form as MyUserForm
Set form = New MyUserForm
form.SomeVar = "Hi"
form.Show ' Displays "Hi" somewhere on the form
```

and all is fine and dandy. But the following, and this is what strikes me as odd, works as well:

```
MyUserForm.SomeVar = "Hi"
MyUserForm.Show
```

which looks like there's some implicitly declared *object* `MyUserForm` whose type is precisely the  *class* `MyUserForm`! What is VBA really doing here? What are the rules governing this strange idiom? Thank you

Comment: well, make two `MyUserForm` instances and then call `MyUserForm.Show` and you will discover the hierarchy. One of the two `MyUserForm` is the active userform and you can reference it by `MyUserForm.<whatever>` but it's bad practice when you have more than one userform to call it using class name. It's better and recommended to **always** use a variable name that stores reference to the specific instance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. When a userform gets added to UserForms collection, you can reference it by its name in VBA code. One instance of it is ready for use immediately - you don't have to create a new instance of it's type. You need to do this if you want to have several of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default instance of the userform.  You should try and avoid it, because you won't have full control over instantiation and destruction.  Have a look at this:

http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VnegO0pMYlIC&pg=PA379&lpg=PA379&dq=automatic+instantiation+of+userforms+in+vba&source=bl&ots=DvHFJkO9Pz&sig=ZiQwsbmqd39kZrwO_joMxNBcwnI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_-sWU4-gAZSShQf39oDoAg&ved=0CEgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=automatic%20instantiation%20of%20userforms%20in%20vba&f=false

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find on my own.